# Mypy with class variable that is an instance of the class

Tags: python, mypy

I am trying to have a class with a class variable that represents an empty instance of the class.  What I currently have is

```
from collections import namedtuple
# from typing import Optional

_Thing = namedtuple("_Thing", ["foo", "bar"])

class Thing(_Thing):
    __slots__ = ()

    def baz(self):
        print("foo", self.foo)

    # NameError: name 'Thing' is not defined
    # EMPTY = Thing(None, None)

Thing.EMPTY = Thing(None, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thing = Thing.EMPTY

    thing.baz()

    print("Done")
```

I am also trying to run Mypy on the code. When I run `python simple.py`, it runs as expected:

```
$ python simple.py && mypy simple.py 
foo None
Done
simple.py:15: error: "Type[Thing]" has no attribute "EMPTY"
simple.py:18: error: "Type[Thing]" has no attribute "EMPTY"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

but Mypy is unhappy because the declaration for `Thing` does not define `EMPTY`.

If I uncomment the definition of `EMPTY` inside the class, I get a `NameError` because I am trying to reference `Thing` while it is being defined.

If I try to declare `EMPTY` in the class as `EMPTY = None` and assign it outside the class, Mypy is unhappy because it thinks the type of `EMPTY` is `None`.

If I try to annotate `EMPTY` with `Optional[Thing]` as a type, then I get back to using `Thing` before it is defined.

Is there a solution to this, or do I just need to tell Mypy to ignore the `EMPTY` field?

I am using python 3.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate a variable without assigning it a value. This is useful here because you can't use the name of the type `Thing` to create an instance within its own class body, because the global name `Thing` doesn't get defined until *after* the class object is created. So you want just an annotation, with the value to be defined later.

The lack of the global name `Thing` is also why your attempts so far at annotating the attribute didn't work. The solution for this is to make a forward reference using a quoted string. You can use `"Thing"` to annotate where an instance of your class will be, before `Thing` is defined.

(Python 3.11, which comes out in fall 2022, will include [PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/), which will offer an even better way to refer to "the current class" from within a class's body or methods: `typing.Self`. It would be perfect for solving our forward reference problem, but it's not out yet.)

Annotating an attribute in a class body normally tells the type checker that the attribute will be an instance variable (this is the default assumption that type checkers will make). If you intend the attribute to be a class variable, you need to show that by using `typing.ClassVar` in the annotation.

So, putting this all together, you probably want something like this:

```
import typing

class Thing(_Thing):
    EMPTY: typing.ClassVar["Thing"]
    #...

Thing.EMPTY = Thing(None, None)
```

If you ever upgrade this code to Python 3.11, you can replace `"Thing"` in the annotation with `typing.Self`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the deleted answer (vote to undelete if you can):

> Note, if you use
>
> ```
> from __future__ import annotations
> ```
>
> You can just do:
>
> ```
> ...
> class Thing(_Thing):
>     EMPTY: typing.ClassVar[Thing]
>     ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I declare classes like this in this kind of situation.

```
from typing import ClassVar
from typing import Self

class Thing:
    EMPTY_THING: ClassVar[Self]

    @classmethod
    def __defaults__(cls) -> None:
        cls.EMPTY_THING = cls()

Thing.__defaults__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert Thing.EMPTY_THING is not None
```